# Reg ex to check phone number

Tags: regex

Phone number must be in the format 89xxxxxxxxx, so it must start from 89, contain only digits and contain eleven digits in common.
I tried this reg expression `^(89)[0-9]{9}$` https://regex101.com/r/rB4rJ3/1 but it doesn't work. How to make it work?

Comment: It works, just add `gm` flags.

Comment: Your test case is two phone numbers on two lines. The regex matches only one phone number.

Comment: I used two phone numbers only for test purposes. I will be one number, of course, but I would like to undestand how it works. It seems, with `gm` flags the check works correctly.

Comment: The parentheses around `89` accomplish nothing.

Comment: @torazaburo thank you, I will remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you did with your regex is you have used `^` and `$`. Note that these should be used only when you wish your `string` to completely match the `regex`

Your regex `^(89)[0-9]{9}$` says that match the string having **only** first two digits as `8` and `9` then followed by 9 digits ranging from `0-9`. That's why it's failing to match 
`89208713060`
 
`89208713065`
Which are two 10 digit numbers on separate lines.

If your input is only a 10 digit number in one line then your regex is fine. 
But if you wish to match 10 digit numbers in a file or some other string you should drop *anchoring* and use [standard form](https://regex101.com/r/rB4rJ3/2).